# How would I setup the Environment Variables for BulletPhysics?

Tags: c++, ogre, bullet-physics, mingw

I am using [Bullet Physics](http://bulletphysics.org/wordpress/) v2.78. And Im trying to build this library to be used for [ogrebullet](http://www.ogre3d.org/addonforums/viewtopic.php?f=12&t=4155). The main problem is that Im getting errors trying to find the Bullet Directory.

Im wondering if maybe my environment variables are setup wrong.

I am using Windows Vista 32 bit, and here are my Environment variables:

BULLET_ROOT: C:\BulletPhys

BULLET_INCLUDE_DIR: C:\BulletPhys\src

as other information I am trying to build these libraries in [cMake](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/resources/software.html). Bullet physics builds perfectly, but ogrebullet cant find the libraries needed to configure(Dynamics, Collision, LinearMath, etc.)

So my question is: How would I setup the environment variables so ogrebullet can find them?

If any other information is needed i will provide upon request.

Thanks

-Molma

Answer (score 1):

After building bullet, you have to copy the libs to the ogre folder as explained [here](http://www.ogre3d.org/tikiwiki/OgreBullet+Tutorial+1&structure=Libraries)

Particulary this part: **"Put these files to ....\OgreBullet\lib\Debug\:"**

Comment: Yes I did this step already, the first thing I did actually ._. does it matter what the filenames are called? mine have the prefix `lib-` in each file.

Comment: Yes the file names are important, don't change them if not explicitely stated in the link above, just do what it says

Comment: Hm...thats odd, because thats how my libraries were outputted when building..maybe i should change the name to what they say in the tutorial?

Comment: Yes that sounds good

Comment: alright, ill do that. But it will be a while before i can reply...In class right now, so I have to get back home first since its on my computer.

Comment: oh another question. I noticed that it requires .lib, my libraries are .a, as in `libBulletCollision.a` is there any way that i can change that?

Comment: Which platform are you on? I thought you were on windows, that is a linux library. Or did you build it with cygwin/mingw?

Comment: i built with cMake for MinGW. Would it still work if a built as a .lib and used it in CodeBlocks(MinGW)?

Comment: If you do that you must really know what you do, which (no offense) is not the case here. My advice is read the doc and do exactly step be step what they say. Again, no offense, that is what they made this doc for ;)

Comment: hm..I guess i can build bullet for VC++(its possible with cMake) im going to try that and see where i get. First thing first, I gotta be home xD

Comment: Sure, take your time

Comment: Alright, Im home but i have another problem. When configuring Bullet in cmake, i got an error saying that `CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM was not set`. Also when opening the project file(BULLETPHYSICS.sln) I get an error in VC2008(v9) saying that its not compatible(the vcproj fiels)...and ideas?

Comment: this is what i installed: [Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Express Editions with SP1](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=f3fbb04e-92c2-4701-b4ba-92e26e408569)

Comment: Just a quick question though..Should I even bother using ogrebullet, when i am using Ogre3D and BulletPhysics?

Comment: Hello? Im still having this problem, the main thing im asking now is if theres a possible program to convert the `.a` files into MSVC `.lib` files